# Is 明朝 a typo for 早朝?

Tags: manga

I am puzzled by the use of 明朝 in the below panel.

[image]

Using 明朝 here would be quite a wordy way to say ５日後の早朝. I checked an English translation today and it seems like 明朝 actually means 早朝?

Comment: Any more context available?  If they're talking about time travel, for instance, this 明朝 might be referring to the Ming Court of imperial China.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi No, these girls are entertainers. They are learning about events happening in the next 7 days.

Comment: 明朝 means *tomorrow morning*. As it says 4日後, most probably it's a typo.

Comment: @sundowner, it's a stretch, but any chance they mean _"after four days, the next morning..."_ in reference to the morning of the 5th day? A typo from 変換ミス seems unlikely given the difference in readings.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi yea, it could be but rather unnatural a way to put it (It uses 7日後に, so not using 5日後の朝 is very odd). Probably it is easier to read on to know the answer (if the story is clear about which day).

Comment: Is it from a published work? If so, what is the title?

Comment: @YusukeMatsubara It's from the latest chapter of the manga series oshi no ko

Comment: Errors can slip in to those weekly publications more often than books. This might be one of them. They usually fix them when publishing in book form.

Answer (score 11):

4日目の明朝 technically might mean "the 4th day's next day's morning" or "the morning after the 4th day". If everyone understands that "the 4th day" is much more important than the other days, one might refer to the 5th day's morning like this. Still, even in such cases, it's more natural to say 4日目の次の朝 or 4日目の翌朝 instead. In the context of this manga, there seems to be no preestablished understanding that the "4th day" is special, so the phrase 4日目の明朝 sounds very puzzling. I agree with the opinion that it's *probably* a typo for 早朝.